# Why wont this Gradle based Spring Boot project serve static resources when running within IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gradle

Whilst using IntelliJ Idea, I´ve come across a difference between creating a practically identical Spring Boot Initializr project for Maven Project and the same but for a Gradle Project.

When creating and running the Maven based project, and adding a simple index.html to src/main/resources/static, accessing localhost:8080 in the browser shows the index.html as expected.

However when attempting exactly the same but with a Gradle based project, it yields a Whitelabel Error Page, due to a 404 not found error.

I also noticed in the output, the Maven project does mention

`o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]`

whereas this is not showing in the output from the Gradle version.

Can anyone help confirm whether this issue an issue with IntelliJ and whether I need to further configure the Gradle params in order to 'see' and serve the static resources.

Note the bootRun gradle task works as expected, so it does look like it´s the way Intellij launches the project. it doesn´t package up the resources folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Why the quick downvote?  Don´t you think I´ve researched this?  I´ve done considerable research into this issue but haven´t found a valid explanation, hence reverting to the community!   At least provide a constructive comment rather than lurk in the shadows gracelessly down-voting.

Comment: Which versions of Spring Boot, IntelliJ, and Gradle are you using?

Comment: Hi, Spring Boot 2.2.4,  And the latest IntelliJ and whichever Gradle is provided. Looks to be 6.0.1

Comment: Just to add to this,  I´ve noticed there isn´t an issue if the project is initialised for Groovy,  it´s only the Java version that is misbehaving.